# Expected Variance of EM Estimator in GMM with Respect to Observations

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, classification, gaussian-mixture-distribution, expectation-maximization

#### Title:

Variance of EM Estimator in GMM with Respect to Observations

#### Body:

I'm estimating a parameter `S` from observations `X` and `Z` using a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) for `P_{S|XZ}` and the Expectation-Maximization (EM) algorithm. I seek to understand the variance of this estimator concerning `X`.

- **Model**: `P_{S|XZ}` follows a GMM.
- **Goal**: Compute the variance of the estimator for `S` with respect to `X`.

##### Questions:

1. How to compute or approximate this variance given the GMM and EM approach?
2. Any specific EM or GMM properties to consider for this variance calculation?
3. Suggestions for practical numerical methods or approximations for this estimation?

##### Context:

- The role of the Fisher Information Matrix (FIM) in estimating variance is understood, but its computation in GMMs seems complex.
- Interested in how the EM algorithm's properties affect variance calculation.
- Open to numerical approximation methods or empirical techniques for practical estimation.

Looking for insights or literature on estimating variance in GMMs using EM, especially concerning specific observations.